# Maximizing $\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}|\operatorname{deg}\ x_{i}-\operatorname{deg}\ x_{j}|^{3}$ over all simple graphs with $n$ vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-optimization, extremal-combinatorics

For a simple graph $G$ on $n$ vertices, let us define

$$\mathcal{I}_{n}(G)=\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}|\operatorname{deg}\ x_{i}-\operatorname{deg}\ x_{j}|^{3}$$

I am highly interested in finding $\sup \mathcal{I}_{n}$ over all graphs with $n$ vertices (or at least some tight upper bound). What I have tried myself, was noticing that $\mathcal{I}_{n}$ must be maximized by a threshold graph:

> Sketch of proof: This index $\mathcal{I}_{n}$ is a convex function of degree sequence
>   $\operatorname{deg} \ x_{1},...,\operatorname{deg} \ x_{n}$. Call the set of all such graphic sequences $D$. Then we
>   can look on $D^{∗}=\mathcal{Con}D$ - a convex hull of $D$. It must then attain it's
>   maximum on some extreme point of $D^{∗}$. It can be shown, that such
>   extreme points of $D^{*}$ are exactly those corresponding to threshold
>   graphs.

But this didn't lead me too far. I will be glad for any insight.

Simulations show that the optimum occurs for $k$ isolated vertices and a complete graph on the other $n−k$ where $k=\lfloor\frac{n+1}5\rfloor$. The same count occurs for $k$ vertices of degree $n−1$ and no other edges so the other $n−k$ have degree $k$. Do You have any ideas on how to prove it?